# How to start gunicorn with sudo permission on flask

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm trying to save file on ec2 instance using Python and flask,

path: download/generate_file_name.pdf

but I have "[Errno 13] Permission denied:"

I tried:

```
gunicorn --user=root --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi --Error-logfile /var/log/flog/error.log
```

But after this I have an error: OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/wgunicorn-kKEd4G'

sudo gunicorn - also doesn't work! I already shared permissions for this download folder chmod 777 - doesn't work

What do I need to do for save file in local folder inside ec2

Answer (score -1):

Solved by:

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 download
```